# What is the difference between following Predicate Logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

$\forall x \forall y \left (( Mother(x) \ \Lambda\ Loves(x,y)\right) \rightarrow child(y,x))$

$\forall x \forall y\left (( Mother(x) \ \Lambda\ child(y,x)\right) \rightarrow Loves(x,y))$

---

For 2nd one, I think it is appropriate to say

> Every Mother loves her children

But, I am unable to translate 1st one into English ?

Comment: In case 1, mothers don't love their husbands.

Comment: @DanielV  Sorry, didn't get ?

Comment: I think it's perhaps supposed to be 'every mother loves only her child'. The problem is that there could be mothers that doesnt love any one. So maybe 'a mother loves noone else but her child'.

Comment: Note that the question is actually meaningless until you specify what "$child(x,y)$" and "$loves(x,y)$" mean, because the order of the inputs matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is like the statement 'Only Americans are nice', which would be translated as:

$\forall x (Nice(x) \rightarrow American(x))$

but may be more easily understood by looking at its contrapositive equivalent:

$\forall x (\neg American(x) \rightarrow \neg Nice(x))$

We can do the same for this statement about mothers:

$\forall x \forall y\left (( Mother(x) \ \land\ Loves(x,y)\right) \rightarrow Child(y,x)) \Leftrightarrow$

$\forall x \forall y\left (Mother(x) \rightarrow (Loves(x,y)\right) \rightarrow Child(y,x))) \Leftrightarrow$

$\forall x \forall y\left (Mother(x) \rightarrow (\neg Child(y,x)\right) \rightarrow \neg Loves(x,y))) $

And so now you get that a mother does not love anything that is not their child or: ''Mothers only love their children"

By the way, in the first step I used Exportation, which says $P\rightarrow (Q \rightarrow R) \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \rightarrow R$

Answer (score 0):

Literally you can see it is saying if a mother loves something, then that something is necessarily her child. I'll let you translate it more eloquently.